# Does timer.cancel() return the timer as null?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, timer

I have a `timer` object in java. The following is my code:

```
package com.krish.timerproject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnStart, btnStop, btnPause;

    int  x = 0;

    Timer timer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnStart = findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        btnPause = findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
        btnStop = findViewById(R.id.btnStop);




        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (timer != null){
                    return;
                }
                timer = new Timer();

                timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d("testingTimer", String.valueOf(x));
                        x++;
                    }
                }, 0, 1000);
            }
        });

        btnPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (timer != null){
                    timer.cancel();
                }

            }
        });

        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (timer != null){
                    timer.cancel();
                }
                x=0;

            }
        });
    }
}
```

If I call `timer.cancel()`does it terminate the timer and return it as null, or does the timer object still exist? Therefore, do I have to set `timer = null;` after `timer.cancel()`?

I was wondering this since after I clicked the pause button and then the start button, my timer didn't resume(it went into the `if(timer !=null){return;}`

Comment: The `timer` object has no knowledge whether and how many references of it exist in the JVM. You need to set the reference to `null` yourself. However this will not destroy the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Javadoc of `java.util.Timer#cancel`:

> Terminates this timer, discarding any currently scheduled tasks. Does not interfere with a currently executing task (if it exists). Once a timer has been terminated, its execution thread terminates gracefully, and no more tasks may be scheduled on it.
> Note that calling this method from within the run method of a timer task that was invoked by this timer absolutely guarantees that the ongoing task execution is the last task execution that will ever be performed by this timer.
> This method may be called repeatedly; the second and subsequent calls have no effect.

As you see, it cancels the scheduled tasks without interrupting running tasks.

The timer object changes its state when you do this but it does not set itself to `null`.

In fact there is no way for an object to modify references to itself so it cannot set itself `null` because [`this`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3) cannot be set to something else, even though you might be able to mutate its content, and even if it could that wouldn't affect other references to the object.

In your program, you explicitly have to set the `timer` variable to `null`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I still don't really understand primary expressions though(even after reading the link). If you could explain it and how it relates to an object unable to modify itself, I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: My fault. I removed the primary expression stuff from the answer. Primary expressions are kind of the main expressions meaning all expressions derive from them.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand it now.